# regular expression with javascript language

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working in Jquery

Is it possible to take a fragment from String variable? such as:

```
var text = "azerty uiop hello qsdf ghjklm wxcvbn";
```

I want take "hello" with 5 symboles before and after:

```
uiop Hello qsdf
```

Comment: jQuery won't really help you with string manipulation.. But yeah, easily done with pure JS.

Comment: jQuery is a library primarily designed to simplify DOM manipulation. With anything else, jQuery is unlikely to help you and you have to use "plain" JS (or other libraries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var text = "azerty uiop hello qsdf ghjklm wxcvbn";
console.log((text.match(/.{0,5}hello.{0,5}/) || [''])[0]); // uiop hello qsdf
```

Comment: +1, I'd also use `{0,5}` in case the match is at a position which doesn't have 5 characters before or after.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you, although it depends on the use case if "up to five" characters is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract a fragment of a string using the substring function -

```
var text = "azerty uiop hello qsdf ghjklm wxcvbn";
var target = text.indexOf("hello");
print(text.substring(target-5,target+10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex in plain javascript:

```
/.{5}hello.{5}/.exec(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "azerty uiop hello qsdf ghjklm wxcvbn";
text.match(/.{5}hello.{5}/)[0]; // uiop hello qsdf
```